# Python which is more efficient; if x !=y: x = y, or x = y

Tags: python, optimization

I've been working with python and pygame recently, and I was wondering, is it more efficient, processor/RAM wise to use `if x != y: x = y` or `x = y` in my main loop? I understand that the difference would be so small that it would make next to no difference, but I am still curious.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at here... the first statement has 2 components, an if statement and an assignment, the second statement just has the same assignment. So, wouldn't it make sense that the second is faster?

Comment: Not necesarily: aren't comparisons faster than assignments? Then if "almost every time" x == y then it'd probably faster to check first, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = y` doesn't require a comparison, and a comparison can be resource costy sometimes.
So I would say that just `x = y` is better.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's point is that sometimes the comparison is false and then you don't need an assignment.

Comment: I see his point, but comparison, as far as I know, is more expensive (in terms of resources) than assignment.